# Is it possible to remove the dot from each of the following values?

Tags: python

I have the following matrices.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2104], [1,1416], [1,1534], [1,852]])

B = np.array([[-40, 0.25], [200, 0.1], [-150, 0.4]])

#print(matmult(A, B))

results = np.matmul(B,A.transpose())

print()

print(results)

print()

print(np.round(results.transpose()))
```

I am conducting a matrix multiplication.

my results look like this 4x3 matrix

```
[[486. 410. 692.]
 [314. 342. 416.]
 [344. 353. 464.]
 [173. 285. 191.]]
```

Is there a way for me to remove the trailing period (".") from the values, such that 486. will be converted to a plain 486?

Comment: if you are sure all the values in your matrix are integers then do `results.astype(int)`. Though the dot is there to indicate that you are dealing with `double/float` values

Comment: here is the actual results, without rounding:

```
[[486.  314.  343.5 173. ]

 [410.4 341.6 353.4 285.2]

 [691.6 416.4 463.6 190.8]]


```

after using the np.rounding() function, I am left with the period at the end.  

If I implement the astype(int), I do not get the rounding feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot is there because it is an array of floating point numbers. Convert them to integers if you are sure they have integer values.

See:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Try this:

```
np.round(results.transpose()).astype(int)
```

Comment: here is the actual results, without rounding: ``` [[486. 314. 343.5 173. ] [410.4 341.6 353.4 285.2] [691.6 416.4 463.6 190.8]] ``` after using the np.rounding() function, I am left with the period at the end. If I implement the astype(int), I do not get the rounding feature.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot to move the conversion outside the rounding function. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Yes, adding the astype(int) outside of the rounding worked.